# About 'CASE' a conversion failure

Tags: sql-server

While using '`CASE`' I encountered with problem that I'D never heard.
The problem is so: I'M using '`CASE`' statement in '`SELECT`' clause as a field. When calling columns with int data type, it's successful; However, When calling a varchar or datetime, it's unsuccessful.
İn the error result, it's said me to have marked the temporary field, including '`CASE`' statement, as `int`, But not so. Please help...

> The 'STORED PROCEDURE' Content

```
CREATE PROC spRegistry_PersonsGetField
@ID int,
@Field varchar(100)
AS
SELECT CASE @Field 
WHEN 'Name' THEN Name
WHEN 'Surname' THEN Surname
WHEN 'Username' THEN Username
WHEN 'Password' THEN Password
WHEN 'Status' THEN dbo.fnStatus(Status)
WHEN 'EMail' THEN EMail
WHEN 'Tel' THEN dbo.fnIsEmpty(Tel)
WHEN 'Address' THEN dbo.fnIsEmpty(Address)
WHEN 'City' THEN dbo.fnIsEmpty(City)
WHEN 'BirthDate' THEN dbo.fnDate(BirthDate)
WHEN 'Gender' THEN dbo.fnGender(Gender)
WHEN 'Lang' THEN Lang
ELSE NULL
END
AS [Alan] varchar(200)
FROM Registry_Persons
WHERE ID = @ID
```

My Query

> EXEC spRegistry_PersonsGetField 1, 'BirthDate'

The Error Message

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '04/11/2011' to data type int.

Comment: Does your SP work if you pass another param say 'Name'? Does the `dbo.fnDate` function definitely work?

Comment: That function works correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

T-SQL's [Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) rules apply when a `CASE` is evaluated in order to work out what the *single* returned datatype is to be. Since `int` has a higher precedence than `varchar` an implicit conversion to `int` is attempted & subsequently fails.

To fix this, convert your `int` or `datetime` expressions to `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting / converting the BirthDate to a `VARCHAR`.  Something like this.

```
SELECT CASE @Field
   WHEN 'Name' THEN Name
   WHEN 'Surname' THEN Surname
   WHEN 'Username' THEN Username
   WHEN 'Password' THEN Password
   WHEN 'Status' THEN dbo.fnStatus(Status)
   WHEN 'EMail' THEN EMail
   WHEN 'Tel' THEN dbo.fnIsEmpty(Tel)
   WHEN 'Address' THEN dbo.fnIsEmpty(Address)
   WHEN 'City' THEN dbo.fnIsEmpty(City)
   WHEN 'BirthDate' THEN CAST(dbo.fnDate(BirthDate) AS VARCHAR) -- update here
   WHEN 'Gender' THEN dbo.fnGender(Gender)
   WHEN 'Lang' THEN Lang
   ELSE NULL
END AS [Alan] varchar(200)
FROM Registry_Persons
WHERE ID = @ID
```