# SQL Server CASE Conversion failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, case

I am having some trouble with a `CASE` statement,  in that I am getting an error when converting a value from `VARCHAR` to `INT`. I know this is due to precedence constraints and to fix I need to `CONVERT/CAST` one of my values, I am having trouble figuring out which to convert.

This [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106225/about-case-a-conversion-failure) pushed me in the right direction, just banging my head to figure it out.

```
UPDATE  Table1
SET     IntField = ( CASE WHEN ( VARCHARField = 0
                             OR VARCHARField = 1
                             OR VARCHARField = 2
                             OR VARCHARField = 3
                           ) THEN 0
                      WHEN ( VARCHARField = 4
                             OR VARCHARField = 5
                             OR VARCHARField = 6
                             OR VARCHARField = 7
                           ) THEN 1
                      WHEN ( VARCHARField = 8
                             OR VARCHARField = 9
                           ) THEN 2
                      WHEN ( VARCHARField = 'N' ) THEN 3
                      ELSE 0
                 END )
```

Error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'N' to data type int.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you make the comparisons like this instead: `WHEN (VARCHARField = '0' OR VARCHARField = '1' ...` and make `VARCHARField`, well, a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Thank you @EfrainReyes - that was the issue.

Answer (score 7):

This has nothing to do with the `case`.  It is the comparisons.  You care comparing a character field to an integer.  Perhaps you mean:

```
CASE 
    WHEN VARCHARField in ('0', '1', '2', '3') THEN 0
    WHEN VARCHARField in ('4', '5', '6', '7') THEN 1
    WHEN VARCHARField in ('8', '9') THEN 2
    WHEN VARCHARField = 'N' THEN 3
    ELSE 0
END
```

Although, from the substance of the error message, I would guess that `VARCHARField` is actually stored as a numeric value.

Comment: Thanks to you both - a very simple overlook on my part to not have the values within single quotes!  Added those and it worked fine.