# Why I got an int datatype when using conditional case?

Tags: sql-server

Consider the following Sql snippet:

```
declare @param as int
set @param=1
select
case when @param=1 then '987' else '' end as Value1,
case when @param=2 then 987 else '' end as Value2,
case when @param<>2 then '' else 987 end as Value3
```

I would expect to get 1 row with 3 fields:  The string 987 and 2 empty strings but I get the following result:

[image]

Can you explain me please why I got a 0 value? I know it is because the column is interpreted as integer datatype but not sure the reason why.

Comment: An almost-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106225/about-case-a-conversion-failure

Comment: Instead of empty string if a have alphabet you would have got a conversion failed error

Answer (score 3):

At the moment of writing the question I found the answer:

This behaviour is due to the [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence. If the conversion is not a supported implicit conversion, an error is returned. When both operand expressions have the same data type, the result of the operation has that data type.

for more information

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx